# In gnuplot the first and the last points connect to each other

Tags: gnuplot

What can I do to prevent gnuplot from connecting the very first and last points together?

This is the format I use:

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
#set format x "%H:%M:%.3S"
set xdata time
set datafile sep ','
set term jpeg
set output 'oputput.jpeg'
plot 'input.csv' some_title using 1:$index title '$name' with lines
```

Sample input file:

```
00:11:37.220,registerUser,2457,285
00:15:12.566,registerUser,1171,219
00:21:34.024,registerUser,89,234
00:27:35.545,registerUser,95,261
00:29:12.458,registerUser,1207,19
00:35:22.269,registerUser,1257,257
.
.
.
23:29:40.704,registerUser,1753,216
23:30:23.672,registerUser,101,17
23:40:47.221,registerUser,101,283
23:49:18.986,registerUser,105,366
23:57:36.886,registerUser,102,238
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, does it really show with you example data? With the data you show, fixing your plot command (`plot 'input.csv' using 1:3 title 'name' with lines`) and using `set format x '%H'` I get http://i.stack.imgur.com/JxZht.jpg Which gnuplot version do you use?

Comment: This happens often to me when I write the same data again to the same file, and append, instead of overwrite. Check if that is happening with the way you create the data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give two answers, one through manipulating data and one using gnuplot:

### 1) check/remove the last line of the data file

When your issue happens it usually means that there is a spurious data point at the end of the file (or somewhere in the middle) that draws that line.  **Check your input data**.  I don't think gnuplot has a setting to connect the last and first lines, but to be safe you can put the command

```
reset
```

at the beginning of your script.

### 2) use `stats` to count the N lines in the file and only plot N-1 lines

To do this you need gnuplot version >= 4.6.0.

```
# do stats first to get number of records; doesn't work in time mode
stats 'input.csv' nooutput
N = STATS_records - 2

set term jpeg size 1200,1000
set output 'output.jpeg'

set xdata time
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set datafile sep ','

plot 'input.csv' some_title using 1:$index every ::::N title '$name' with lines
```

Type `help every` at the gnuplot command prompt if the syntax is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: there was an issue with the data really. thanks for the help.